# How to get the id of the item being focused as a result of KeyEvent in GridView?

Tags: android

I am executing **KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP**, as a result one of the item in GridView gains focus. My requirement is to obtain the id(or position) of that item. Is it possible to get it? Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

Comment: you can get id/position of item from setOnItemClickListener in gridview

Comment: Hi AkashG, thanks for reply. Here, I am executing KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP via. voice command(not using click).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the position of the focused item by using **gridView.setOnItemSelectedListener**.

```
gridView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                int mPosition = pos;
            }
 });
```